# Where are /system/build.prop and /vendor/build.prop stored on the ADB shell side on Lineage 19.x GSI’s?

Tags: android-12, adb

I’m running an ADB shell on my main device, whose ROM was dead due to forgetting to append **emulator** after

```
ro.build.characteristics=tablet
```

, when appended this line becomes

```
ro.build.characteristics=tablet,emulator
```

, on both files in the title.
Since i know where they are, this is solved, i know pull to and push from PC commands inside ADB shell.